# Resize div based on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `Li` tag which shows notification dropdown in my bootstrap theme but the problem is if there is no content inside this `li` tag then also it is shown with `300px` height, I have tried removing that height also but still no luck. How can I resize this `li` tag if there is no content inside it.

Content is shown in media-body tag

```
<li class="dropdown navbar-notification">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-header">
            <span class="title">Notifications 
                <strong>(0)</strong>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-body niceScroll">
            <div class="media-list small">
                <a href="" class="media">
                    <div class="media-object pull-left"><i class="fa fa-ban fg-danger"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <span class="media-text">No new Notification</span>
                        <!-- Start meta icon -->
                        <span class="media-meta"></span>
                        <!--/ End meta icon -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media-body -->
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-footer">
            <a href="https://www.example.com/notification">See All</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

```js
$(".navbar-notification .niceScroll").mouseover(function() {
    $(".navbar-notification .niceScroll").niceScroll({
        cursorwidth: '10px',
        cursorborder: '0px'
    }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select empty element by css `:empty` selector and hide it:

```
element:empty {
    display: none;
}
```